# Android:Spacing between the Linearlayout in java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i am trying to give spacing between the views in a linearlayout programatically , i tried with 
`layout.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);` but nothing worked ..also iam trying to put more space in one edittext field ..tried with this

```
comment.setLayoutParams(newandroid.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(450,100));

//comment.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

here is my code: http://pastebin.com/s46qQUNV

Comment: Please do some searching before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to using LayoutParams :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                     (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f);
params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give padding to each edittextview.

```
    address.setpadding(0,5,0,5) ;
    addressCity.setpadding(0,5,0,5) ;
    addressState.setpadding(0,5,0,5) ;
```

should work.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will make the padding a pixel value. Depending on the size of the pixels the padding will look different on different screens.